# Neem Tree Identification

Tags: identification

I have this Neem tree and was told that they are gender specific. I have tried looking on the internet to no avail. Is there an easy way to identify the gender of a Neem tree?

Answer (score 2):

They are not gender specific - each cluster of flowers bears both male and female flowers, but an individual tree is not capable of pollinating itself. Fruit production is normally low, but increases with  hand pollination;  if you only have one tree and there are no others in the vicinity, you probably need to plant at least one more. Further scientific info here  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/263721622_Reproductive_biology_of_Azadirachta_indica_Meliaceae_a_medicinal_tree_species_from_arid_zones